# C# SharpZipLib strips irrelevant directory names

Tags: c#, compression, zip, directory, archive

I am using [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) to zip up a folder with subdirectories and this is working fine. What I would like to do is strip off the parents directories of the first child file so the whole structure that is irrelevant isn't carried forth...

Example:

c:\a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\file1.txt

c:\a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\file2.txt

c:\a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\file1.txt

c:\a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\file2.txt

It should end up like this:

> file1.txt
>
> file2.txt
>
> i\file1.txt
>
> i\file2.txt

How can I do this?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
        ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(destinationArchive);

        zipFile.BeginUpdate();
        foreach (FileInfo file in sourceFiles)
        {
            zipFile.Add(file.FullName);
        }
        zipFile.CommitUpdate();
        
        zipFile.Close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ZipOutputStream instead:

```
string[] sourceFiles = new [] { @"c:\a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\file1.txt", @"c:\a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\i\file1.txt" };
FileStream fileStream = File.Create(@"c:\temp\test.zip");
ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(fileStream);
string baseDir = @"c:\a\b\c\d\e\f\g\h\";
foreach (var sourceFile in sourceFiles)
{
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(sourceFile.Replace(baseDir,""));
    zipOut.PutNextEntry(entry);

    FileStream inFile =  File.OpenRead(sourceFile);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int bytesRead = 0;
    while ((bytesRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        zipOut.Write(buffer,0,bytesRead);
    }
    zipOut.CloseEntry();                
}
zipOut.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or look on CodePlex for DotNetZip.