# Make a .tar.gz archive without folder structure using SharpZipLib

Tags: c#, .net, sharpziplib

I am trying to .tar.gz a list of files from a folder using SharpZipLib. The problem is no matter how pass the files paths - the result always contains the files paths - and not only the files thems selves. What am i missing here?

```
string filesFolder = "c:\\testfolder\\test\\";
List<string> filesToZip = new List<string>() { filesFolder +"test1", filesFolder  +"test2"};

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filesFolder +"myGz.tar.gz" , FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
using (Stream gzipStream = new GZipOutputStream(fs))
using (TarArchive tarArchive = TarArchive.CreateOutputTarArchive(gzipStream))
     {
      foreach (string filename in filesToZip )
      {
        {
          TarEntry tarEntry = TarEntry.CreateEntryFromFile(filename);
          tarArchive.WriteEntry(tarEntry, false);
        }
      }
     }
```

what i get is a "myGz.tar.gz" files. When i try to open it with  7.zip - i get the full folders structure in the archive - c:\testfolder\test\, and in it - "test1", "test".

How do i remove the files paths?

Thanks

Comment: This could be useful: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350653/c-sharp-sharpziplib-strips-irrelevant-directory-names

Comment: That is because you are telling it too! Why do you think it do it any way else?

Comment: I didn't see any other way to add to tar without giving it the full file path. M Sakher Sawan - thank you! it does work on zip files - but i couldn't find a paraplel example for .gz files

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, and I figured it out just after finding this question.

The key is to set the `Name` property of the `tarEntry`, before adding it into the archive.

```
TarEntry tarEntry = TarEntry.CreateEntryFromFile(filename);
tarEntry.Name = Path.GetFileName(filename);
tarArchive.WriteEntry(tarEntry, false);
```